# Struts 2 ajax validation unable to find interceptor class jsonValidationWorkflowStack

Tags: java, ajax, validation, struts2, dojo

I'm trying to implement ajax validation in my Struts 2 application. I have included struts2-json-plugin in the build path. Whenever I start the server in Eclipse, I get the following error:

> Unable to find interceptor class referenced by ref-name
>   jsonValidationWorkflowStack - interceptor-ref -
>   file:/C:/path/struts.xml:15:60

This is what my struts.xml looks like:

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.url.includeParams" value="all" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="submitForm" class="action.FormAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
        <result>results.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>  
</struts>
```

Why is this happening? I'm following the official struts2 ajax validation tutorial [at](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/ajax-validation.html.).

Answer (score 6):

You need to extend the `"json-default"` package.

The `"struts-default"` package doesn't know about the `"jsonValidationWorkflowStack"`.

Comment: what would that look like? 
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default">?

Comment: @pgpgpgpg Um... it would look like `extend="json-default"`.

Comment: oh. so does json-default already extend struts-default? in any case the error has stopped showing. validation still isn't working but i'll poke around with it more. thx

Comment: @pgpgpgpg Yes. You can verify this by looking at the plugin's config file.